# How is the evaluation environment retained after a promise has been turned into a call?

Tags: r, promise, evaluation

In the following minimal working example, `a_promise` is turned into `a_call` using `substitute()`. I can see that the `a_promise` object store both the expression and the environment where that expression should be evaluated.

However, as far as I can tell, once it's turned into `a_call`, the only thing that `a_call` stores is simply the expression (`condition`) with no reference to the environment in which that expression can be evaluated and turned into `a >= 4`.

However, the error at the end indicates that `eval(a_call, df, parent.frame()` does try to look for object `a`, meaning that `a_call` was indeed translated into `a >= 4`. How?

```
library(pryr)
f <- function(df, a_promise) {
  print(promise_info(a_promise)) #> shows both the expression and the eval envir
  a_call <- substitute(a_promise)
  print(a_call) #> condition
  eval(a_call, df, parent.frame())
}

g <- function(df, condition) {
  f(df, condition)
}

df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=5:1)
g(df, a >= 4)
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
a_call <- substitute(a_promise)
```

you are getting the expression that was passed to `a_promise` which is `condition`. The class of `a_call` is `symbol` (not a call or expression). This `symbol` is really a pointer to another promise in the parent frame that hasn't been resolved yet. So by the time you're at `f`, you've missed your chance to turn `a >= 4` into an expression in the usual `substitute` way. Now, when you ask for the value of `condition` you are evaluating the previous promise and getting a non-sensical result. It really comes down to the difference between

```
eval( a >= 4, df)
# Error in eval(a >= 4, df) : object 'a' not found
```

and

```
eval( expression(a >= 4), df)
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE.
```

When `condition` is resolving it's promise, it's not doing so inside your `eval()`.

Comment: When I `print(a_call)`, the only thing I get back is `condition`. Is there a way for me to prove to myself that it is indeed a pointer to another promise to the parent frame (which I understand to be the promise `condition`, to be evaluated in `g()` execution environment, and thus translated into `a >= 4`, correct?)

Comment: When you `print(a_call)` you get `condition` because `a_call` is a symbol and `print(as.symbol("anything"))` will always just print `anything`. You are not actually printing the value that that symbol points to. To get the value you would typically just do `print(a_promise)` but in this particular case this raises an error because `a` doesn't exist. Like I said before normally you can't see promises using just R code. The `pryr` `promise_info` function uses C++ code to peek and i'm not sure if it's capable of extracting a promise from a different frame.

Comment: I'm not sure you noticed but you just answered 3 of my questions recently as I'm trying to work through Hadley's Advanced R book. Thank you truly! How did you learn about all this? I'm venturing into the inner workings of R and Hadley's book, while great, is too minimal at times.

Comment: I've been working with R for like 6 years now. I've answered lots of questions in chat rooms over the years and now recently on this site. I learn a lot by helping others. I may not always know the answer right away, but i'm able to experiment based on what I do know, test out hypotheses, and refine my mental model for what's going on to find an answer. If i'm wrong, others will correct me and I still end up learning more. In my own code I try to use non-standard evaluation sparingly. It's usually not worth all the trouble.